# Identification: Real time strategy game for PC between 2003 to 2012, has magic and wyrms

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Somewhere between 2003 and 2012 I have played a demo of a real time strategy game. I would like to find it again.

Here's what I know (every point is sketchy, except last one):

1. It was 3d with free camera (not isometric).
2. Units had quite realistic proportions , not cartoony with big hands/heads or too bright colors like Warcraft. I think it was quite pretty for the time. Map might have involved a huge, pretty waterfall.
3. You could gather stone and wood.
4. Your hero could throw magic
5. You could produce archers and swordsmen and I think calvary.
6. The demo mission tried to hurry you up. You were supposed to fortify your base a bit, quickly build minimal forces then free the rest of the map / move from the starting part of the map to the stone passage on the other part of it. The game was lying about that part (see 9), because time limit was 3 hours I think.
7. Your units could level up (I think three times) / gain veteran status. The units didn't stack in the GUI (3 archers, 2 swordsmen, 1 hero) but were separate (archer, archer, archer,swordsman, swordsman, hero), yet you could hotkey a lot of units at once.
8. One of the creatures that could attack you (and new ones did attack you once every 2-5 minutes) was some sort of poison-spitting dragon/wyrm type units (think Dota 2 Venom) which melted unfortified archers. It could still be easily killed if you stacked 8 of them. Or 1-3 of them in the tower.
9. You could build watchtowers and fill them with archers (I think 6 would fit in the tower). There was a position on the map where you could position a tower so your archers easily killed those "flying venom units" that came down the road. That lead to your archers quickly gaining experience and veteran status. I remember it was very easy to keep replacing veteran archers with freshly popped ones in the tower, so they would gain experience. I'd end up with a lot of veteran archers(20 or more) which would make the rest of the mission a cakewalk. That's how I know the game was lying about hurrying up.

I would really like to play that game. I thought it might be one of the Spellforce games (which I never played) but I don't recognize the mission. If it is and you do, please let me know. If it is some other game, I would also like to know, so I can buy it. Thank you.

Comment: I started randomly looking in this list (starting in 2000): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_real-time_strategy_video_games

Comment: Could be one of the "Myth" games maybe?

Comment: @Clockwork I tried looking. It is not one of Myth games, the graphics were much better. Spellforce 3 looks like it might be it but I can't find the wyrm thingie so I am not sure it is the right game.

Comment: @Clockwork thanks a lot, found it after seriously combing the link you provided.

Comment: Over the course, I realise that the best way to find what we are looking for is brute forcing/trying hard enough, but not without narrowing down the fields as much as possible (in this case: a list of RTS games, although it would have been moot if the game was omitted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it after spending two hours looking through the list provided by Clockwork. The game is called "[Armies of Exigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armies_of_Exigo)", came out in 2004. Thing that clicked was looking through playthrough video and hearing the priest unit saying "I must tend my flock".

Oddly enough, that's the annoying part of the game I have suppressed, because that's all the dialogue options that specific unit has and it tells it every time you click on it. So it seared itself in my mind.

The difference is in 7th point: the units could level up 5 times, not 3.

As well as 6th point. Instead of "move from the starting part of the map to the stone passage on the other part of it", there was indeed stone passage, but it lead to the underground map you had to clear, not to the end of the level. I always played it by clearing the above ground map and moving all my forces to the stone passage to clear the "underground map" so it was always the end of mission for me when I reached the stone passage.

The mission I played is here, although that player doesn't do the wyrm farming part (his archers get killed by one at 28 minute mark).